# Connect Galaxy Smart Watch to Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

i am developing an app for wearOS and I want to debug it in my samsung galaxy Watch 4 with wearOS 3.5. If a connect via wifi i can debug it but i would want debut it via bluetooth too. I connect my mobile to the computer via USB but when i tried to connect the smartwatch with ADB the state of the connection is offline and android Studio tell me that my mobile does not have a watch.
I have read the sections of android developers talking about this but i couldn't discover a solution.

How can i solve this? thanks for the help

adb devices
List of devices attached
RZ8T512MQ3M     device
127.0.0.1:4444  offline

The first one is my mobile connected via USB